# How can i compare a string in arraylist with char type of array

Tags: java

Recently i started learning java. And after some knowledge i starts with some program. so i create a Jumble Word game. it works but i have a problem. Here is my code....

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
class JumbleWords
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList <String>alist = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList <Character>chars = new ArrayList<Character>();
    Random rd = new Random();
    int listLimit,charLimit,value,ulimit=0,counter=0;
    String string,temp;
    alist.add("done");
    alist.add("nest");
    alist.add("rat");
    alist.add("cat");
    alist.add("hello");
    alist.add("cycle");
    alist.add("chain");
    alist.add("paint");
    alist.add("collect");
    alist.add("your");
    alist.add("gift");
    alist.add("card");
    alist.add("today");
    alist.add("cheer");
    alist.add("what");
    alist.add("time");
    alist.add("share");
    alist.add("build");
    alist.add("help");
    alist.add("success");
    alist.add("career");
    alist.add("access");
    alist.add("learn");
    alist.add("course");
    alist.add("year");
    alist.add("expert");
    alist.add("school");
    alist.add("floor");
    alist.add("season");
    alist.add("education");
    alist.add("spread");
    listLimit = alist.size();
    int i=0;
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("How many JumbleWords you want to play...");
    System.out.println("Max limit is "+listLimit);
    ulimit = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();
    if(ulimit < listLimit )
    {
    while(i<ulimit )
    {
        value = rd.nextInt(listLimit);
        string = alist.get(value);
        for ( char c : string.toCharArray() )
        {
        chars.add( c );
        }
        Collections.shuffle(chars);
        Collections.shuffle(chars);
        System.out.println(chars);
        System.out.println("\nEnter the correct order of the word.");
        temp = scan.nextLine();
        if(string.equalsIgnoreCase(temp)==true){
            System.out.println("You Win......");
            System.out.println("(*^*)");
            System.out.println();
            ++counter;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("You Lose......");
            System.out.println("The correct word is :-");
            System.out.println(string);
            System.out.println("(*_*)");
            System.out.println();

        }
        chars.clear();
        alist.remove(value);
        i++;
    }

    System.out.println("Your Score is "+counter+" out of "+ulimit);
    System.out.println();
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Not enough words we have...");
    System.out.println();
}
}
}
```

now in case of "CHAIN" is suffle and user must input chain for winning but "CHINA" is also a word with same chars. how can i build a logic for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the whole word:

```
while(i<ulimit )
{
    value = rd.nextInt(listLimit);
    string = alist.get(value);
    if(string.equalsIgnoreCase(value)){
        System.out.println("You Win......");
        System.out.println("(*^*)");
        System.out.println();
        ++counter;
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

First, **your code is really not straight readable**.
Variable names are very very bad chosen while you implement a specific matter :
a word game.
Besides **you declare your variables too early** and have also a too broad scope, **which is error prone and don't easy the reading too**.

How to understand these statements without reading the whole code ?

```
string = alist.get(value);
```

Or :

```
if(string.equalsIgnoreCase(temp)==true){
```

It should be something like:

```
String wordToGuess = wordsToGuess.get(value);
```

and :

```
if(wordToGuess.equalsIgnoreCase(userInput)){
```

Instead of using a List of String.

```
 ArrayList <String>alist = new ArrayList<String>();
```

use a List of `WordToGuess` where  each instance will store a `List<String> anagrams` where `WordToGuess` could be declared :

```
public class WordToGuess{
    private List<String> anagrams;
    ...
    public WordToGuess(String... anagrams){
       this.anagrams = Arrays.asList(anagrams);        
    } 

    public String getAnyWord(){
      return anagrams.get(0);
    }

    public boolean contains(String word){
        return anagrams.contains(word.toLowerCase());
    }    
}
```

In this way you have just to check if the input of the user is contained in the List.

So

```
 ArrayList <String>alist = new ArrayList<String>();
```

will become :

```
 List<WordToGuess> wordsToGuess = new ArrayList<WordToGuess>();
```

Favor the interface in the variable type declaration over concrete class.

And you could populate your List in this way :

```
wordsToGuess.add(new WordToGuess("done", "node")); // two possibilities
wordsToGuess.add(new WordToGuess("nest")); // one 
...
wordsToGuess.add(new WordToGuess("chain", "china")); // two
...
```

And the comparing input `String` with the expected `String` :

```
if(wordToGuess.equalsIgnoreCase(userInput)){
```

will become :

```
if(wordsToGuess.contains(userInput)){
```

It is better to keep the ignoring-case task in the provider class that in the client class that may forget it.

Comment: Thanks davidxxx
I trying to learn java. And your suggestions is truly helpful. for example like variable declaration. but till now i just learn ArrayList. and dont know about anagrams and List(may be). So i a beginner. and i will remember your suggestions.
thanks Again.

Comment: @user8338312 You are very welcome. The anagram variable is just a List of String that contains all possible words for a set of letters.

Comment: Thanks again. can you also suggest me some website and e-books for better learming.

Comment: On a so much specific point, I cannot propose a book but to learn fundamentals of the language, Oracle Java online documentation and OCA: Oracle Certified Associate Java SE 8 Programmer could help you.